# When To Get a Custom View's Width and Height Properties

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have a `Class` called `LineGraphView` which is a subclass of `View`. I want to be able to pass some data to this view so that it can then draw accordingly in its `onDraw()` method.

**Analysis Fragment (Where the view is referenced and method is called from)**

```
LineGraphView altitudeGraph;
LineGraphView speedGraph;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, group, saved);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.analysisfrag, group, false);
    this.altitudeGraph = (LineGraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.linegraph_Altitude);
    this.speedGraph = (LineGraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.linegraph_Speed);

    return view;
}
```

My question is, if I then want to be able to access that views width and height attributes using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, when am I able to do so because so far all thats being returned is `0`.

Do I need to create a listener which lets the `LineGraphView's` parent know its ready to be accessed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already creating your own custom view, I would just add some private variables with getters/setters for the information you need to pass. From there, just handle the drawing in your onDraw() method -- from there, you can get your View's width and height (or just the Canvas width and height, which might be the same values).

Comment: The thing is I need to send data from my fragment (which is where my view is inflated from). When can I do that?

Comment: If you've got public setters for the data, you can send it at any time. I may be misunderstanding the question, but it shouldn't matter when you send it, just make sure in your setter that you invalidate and/or requestLayout on the view to make sure it refreshes. Alternately, if you wanted to take the listener route, there is an OnPreDrawListener that you could use. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html

Comment: I managed to get it working the first way you said. Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594216/969325
Basically you are calling getWidth/height too early (during onCreate). I believe you could use a handler to get it after onCreate. You could also try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118459/969325 (using onWindowFocusChanged).